# Searching file using c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a file and searching mutiple value i.e I need to search {Name,Class} and store it in a list or dictionary from the file.I need to use c#.

Ex.
Name: "ABC"
Class: "5th"
He failed in his Exam because of his poor performance.
Name : "CYS"
Class :9th 
He passed in his Exam because of his good performance.
Class :10th
No comments required.

```
         string Filename = @"ClassInfo.fo";
         XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(Filename);
        List<string> xmlValue = new List<string>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                    xmlValue.Add(reader.Value);
                    break;
            }
        }
         string searchString = "Name :"

         var foundIndices = new List<int>(xmlValue.Count);
         int countValue=0;

         Collection<PdfContent> pdfContent = new Collection<PdfContent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < xmlValue.Count; i++)
        {
            if (xmlValue[i] == searchString)
            {
                foundIndices.Add(i);

                pdfContent.Add(new PdfContent
                {
                    Name= xmlValue[indexOfName],
                    Class=xmlValue[indexOfClass]

                });

            }
        }
```

Comment: I am able to get for name but not for Class.Any Solution

Comment: What problems are you getting with the code above?  You've explained what you want to do, you've shown what you've tried but you haven't explained whats wrong with what you've tried.  Please explain.

Comment: I am able to map the search criteria "Name" with my entity name,but how can I search "Class" and map it to "Class" entity.

Comment: It seems that you have an XML file to read. Maybe this could be solved with *linq to xml* (it's hard to tell exact answer, because there's no sample data available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use regular expression to match pattern after reading all text in a string variable of the file

Examples for regex : http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html